# How can i sort NSMutableArray iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios4, nsmutablearray

I have a scenario where the application retrieves information from a json php into an `NSMutableArray`. My question is as follows ; how can i sort the elements by the "time" field?. Also how can i only display the elements that have 'day' as "monday"? (what would the if statement look like?). Thanks for any help on this.

Also the information in the `NSMutableArray` looks as follows ;

```
   Array: (
            {
            Code = 2COS402;
            Core = Yes;
            Credit = 15;
            Day = Monday;
            Facilities = Full;
            Level = 4;
            Module = "Introduction to Computer Programming";
            "Room_Empty" = Yes;
            Teacher = "Mark James";
            Time = "10:45";
            id = 1;
        },
            {
            Code = 2GDP401;
            Core = Yes;
            Credit = 15;
            Day = Monday;
            Facilities = Full;
            Level = 4;
            Module = "Fundamentals of Interactive Games";
            "Room_Empty" = No;
            Teacher = "Will Smith";
            Time = "09:00";
            id = 4;
        },
            {
            Code = 2GDP501;
            Core = Yes;
            Credit = 15;
            Day = Monday;
            Facilities = Full;
            Level = 4;
            Module = "Games Play Design";
            "Room_Empty" = Yes;
            Teacher = "Frank Sinatra";
            Time = "15:00";
            id = 6;
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check [sortUsingComparator:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingComparator%3a) or [sortUsingSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingSelector%3a) methods of `NSMutableArray`. Of course, you'll need to define your custom `NSComparator` or implement a custom method to do that.